# HTTP Service Mule endpoint shows as not listening

Tags: http, port, mule

I have a pretty basic Mule HTTP endpoint service running on a remote Windows Server. When I run netstat on that box, it shows that that port is listening.

However, when I run portqry from my local box on that same box it shows that the port is NOT LISTENING.

Also, when I run my test harness, it says the connection is refused.

Why does the box say it is listening but when I try to reach that port, it says it is not listening.

I am sure the fix for this is simple but it is eluding me. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Mule 3.4.x and using 'localhost' as the host then you should use '0.0.0.0' instead if you need to bind every network interface:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+ESB+3.4.0+Release+Notes#MuleESB3.4.0ReleaseNotes-localhostBehavior

Comment: I actually tried that previously but got an error: Http Request line is malformed: "GET /"

Comment: Can you share the full log and configuration and the request you do?

Comment: The error I was getting was misleading me... the problem is that there was a Health Monitor that was polling the endpoint to see if it was up. The endpoint was actaully listening when I put the 0.0.0.0 host in.

Answer (score 0):

check the mule xml and make sure the http endpoint is inbound and not outbound.